# Emergency Brake light on 2003 Chevy Tracker stays lit

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, troubleshooting

The emergency brake indicator stays lit even though the brake is not engaged. Problem has progressed...early on, it would come on going around corners (?).

Presumably, some sensor needs replacing...

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned going around corners, there is a good chance the problem is your brake fluid level. A lot of vehicles use the same warning light to indicate brake problems as well as emergency brake. If your brake fluid level is borderline, the cornering inertia (pushing the fluid to one side) may have been enough to trigger the sensor.

Check the brake fluid. If it's low, find out why. Either the system is leaking, or it is naturally low due to needing new brake pads. As pads wear down, the fluid has to displace that space in the brake cylinders, so the fluid gets low. If it's low enough to trigger the sensor, then the pads probably need to be replaced. In my experience, if it's this far along, both front and rear pads will be very low.

Don't top off fluid if there is not a leak, as it will come spilling back out when the brake cylinder is pushed back into the calipers.